# SQL Server Identify Gaps between timestamps and output label them separately

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sets of data which have id's and time stamp.

I want to output each gap where the gap is larger than 20 minutes in its own start and end.

Sample Data:

```
IDID timerecord
1    2018-02-26 06:40:28.483
2    2018-02-26 06:42:03.967
3    2018-02-26 06:44:07.277
4    2018-02-26 06:47:25.913
5    2018-02-26 07:04:23.290
6    2018-02-26 10:19:25.063
7    2018-02-26 10:19:57.750
8    2018-02-26 10:21:45.547
9    2018-02-26 10:24:14.297
10   2018-02-26 10:28:17.967
11   2018-02-26 10:30:10.907
12   2018-02-26 10:30:20.627
13   2018-02-26 10:41:39.717
14   2018-02-26 10:43:00.247
15   2018-02-26 10:45:00.120
16   2018-02-26 10:47:13.867
17   2018-02-26 10:49:36.727
18   2018-02-26 17:06:30.333
19   2018-02-26 17:07:55.550
20   2018-02-26 17:09:37.520
21   2018-02-26 17:16:49.487
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42efe/1/0

Expected Output:

```
timestart               timeend
2018-02-26 06:40:28.483 2018-02-26 07:04:23.290
2018-02-26 10:19:25.063 2018-02-26 10:49:36.727
2018-02-26 17:06:30.333 2018-02-26 17:16:49.487
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()` to identify where groups start.  Then do a cumulative sum to assign a group.  And aggregation:

```
select min(timerecord), max(timerecord)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when timerecord < dateadd(minute, 20, prev_tr)
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (order by timerecord) as grp
      from (select t.*, lag(timerecord) over (order by timerecord) as prev_tr
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by grp
order by min(timerecord);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42efe/5) is the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()` with *cumulative* approach :

```
SELECT MIN(timerecord), MAX(timerecord)
FROM (SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN DIFF_MN > 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY IDID) GRP
      FROM (SELECT *, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(timerecord) OVER (ORDER BY IDID), timerecord) AS DIFF_MN 
            FROM Mytable 
           ) T
     ) T
GROUP BY GRP;
```

Here is a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/42efe/8).